# Deploying multiple ARM templates AzureDevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

I have a requirement to deploy only the modified resources to Azure production, we follow a trunk based approach using git to manage ARM templates in source control.

So we cut out a release branch from main and current pipeline copies all the ARM templates and parameter files to a drop location and the release pipeline has individual ARM deployment task for each component.

1. Each time we add a new component we need to modify the release pipeline to deploy, is there a way to automate this? So that any template and parameter files available in drop location get deployed.
2. In the deployment pipeline what can be an approach to identify components for a particular release? As the commit history will have multiple pull request merges done by different developers.

Comment: ARM deployments are idempotent so if the resources haven't change it won't change..

Comment: you also have a what-if command that you can use to chekc the changes before deploying: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell#what-if-commands

Comment: @Thomas I did not know they are idempotent, I will check it. How to pick templates and it's parameters dynamically in a release pipeline as I don't want to create one ARM deployment task for each resource. The intention partly is that in future if there is a new component, we want to avoid modifying the release pipeline.

Comment: you would have to update the release pipeline anyway to override the env specific parameters ?

Comment: Components are accompanied with its environment specific parameters file, like component.dev.parameters.json etc. So the idea is to use a wild card and pattern matching to get the component template and its parameter file for a environment stage in the release pipeline. For example in the dev stage we would use *. Dev.Parameters.Json to the dev specific params similar in other environment stages.

Comment: then you can just create a `env` variable per stage then use it to construct the parameter filename

Comment: Yes that's what I am doing, I think my question was not clear, what I am struggling with is the actual task to deploy multiple templates. The ARM template deployment task does not support multiple template deployment, it's throws an error if the wild card matches multiple files. And I don't want to create one task for each template.

Comment: you probably want to have a look at azure bicep: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview. you can define multiple resource in it own file and it will generate the arm for you. Otherwise you have have a look at linked template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell. The OOB task in azure devops does not allow you to specify multiple templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Thomas for pointing to Azure Bicep, its worth considering for an update. With the current setup that we have I have come up with an approach to deploy just the modified templates.

I used git diff to find the modified files in the latest commit and then use Azure CLI to deploy the files.

I have written it in detail in [my blog post](https://www.beneathabstraction.com/post/selectedarmdeployment/), please suggest if there is anything that can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4167200/thomas). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

You can check [Azure Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview) and define multiple resources in its own file and it will generate the ARM for you. You can also look at the [Using linked and nested templates when deploying Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell).

The OOB task in Azure DevOps does not allow you to specify multiple templates.